# Sending mass APN stops with php

Tags: php, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Every time I send mass APNs out with php I send roughly 8-10 and then the rest fail.  When I try a second time, every time, the rest of the notifications successfully send.  It's never the same device, because I set the devices sent as marked so they don't get a double notification, and I've even disabled permanently the devices it fails on because originally I thought the devices were the problem.  They are all production devices, not test, as these are separated too.  I have had the same results countless times and have no clue why it's happening.

CODE:

```
$date = date("Ymd");
$englishOnly = "en";
$dateHolder = date('Ymd');
$serverTimeInt = date('Gi');


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'mypw';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL . "<br>";

$doubleFix = array();
$clearArray = array();
$pass = true;
?>
<?php
$messageId = 1;
$alertMessage = "My Message";
?>
<?php
$sqlpush = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE ios=1";
$sqlresult = mysql_query($sqlpush);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
$deviceToken = $row['deviceid'];
$badges = $row['badges'];
$messages = explode(',',$row['messages']);
$pass = true;
$messagesUpdate = $row['messages'] . ',' . $messageId;


foreach($messages as $messageCheck)
{
if($messageCheck == $messageId)
{
$pass = false;
}
}

if($pass == true)
{
$sql2 = "UPDATE devices SET badges=badges+1 WHERE deviceid='$deviceToken'";
mysql_query($sql2)
or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());

$message = $alertMessage;

$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => $badges+1
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
echo $payload;
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL . "<br>";
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered to ' . $deviceToken . PHP_EOL . "<br>";

}
}
$doubleFix = $clearArray;

fclose($fp);
?>
<?php
$finish = microtime(TRUE);
$totaltime = $finish - $start;
echo "This script took ".$totaltime." seconds to run";
?>
```

Essentially it connects to the apn service, loops through all my devices, then closes. I'm sending a few thousand notifications.

Anyone else had this problem, or know why it might be happening?

Comment: Do you open connection to Apple server for each message or you do this once and then send all of them one after another?

Comment: I am only opening the connection one time, send all notifications, then close.

Comment: I had exactly same  issue when opening new connection for each request. Apple was throttling new connections after 5-6 times. But after I changed it to this approach - everything worked fine.

Comment: Hmm... yeah a lot of things I read pointed that direction, but I'm actually only opening a single connection for a few thousand notifications, so that can't be the issue here.  Not sure what else it would be?

Comment: You might want to add a small sleep inside the pushing loop. Try with `usleep(100000);` inside the loop. This is how it's done in ApnsPHP for example...

Comment: I thought about adding a sleep but because I'm sending a few thousand notifications it would take over an hour just to send. I don't think that's going to work out for me.